# React Native folder structure best practice

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I cannot find any official best practice to store unit test folder structure for react native project.
Some people they create one folder **tests** to maintain all components of the app.
Some people they create folder **tests** inside each components store all unit test file there.

Can someone point out the right way to store unit test files?